geometry nodes not instancing the correct instances when using instance on points node
I am using geometry nodes to generate curve instances that act as the branches for a tree.  My problem is that I cannot get the instance of the branch with the leaves on it to be instanced properly.  As you can see below, the geometry being plugged in below clearly shows a branch with the leaves attached to it:

but when I attempt to instance that onto the main trunk curve, the leaves disappear:

file: 
(version 4.3)

Hi, please share the file so that we can see the nodes.

thanks for reminding me.  file should be available now

The real reason you can't see the leaves is not because you did something wrong in your setup or the leaves are in the wrong position. All your geometry is still "there", with all the leaves placed correctly, you just can't see them. And the real reason for this is that you have a big "instance tree" in which you have multiple nested instances:

There is a limit on the number of nested instances, after which blender will simply delete (or hide) all child instances. This is written in the official documentation:

I'm not sure why you actually went over 8 levels, since it looks like you have less levels. It might be because I just don't understand what they actually mean by "level", it seems like the fact that each instance has both nested instances and mesh data increases the nesting level, so if you use a Geometry to Instance node on all your mesh data before applying it to the Join Geometry node it will fix the issue.
Another solution (which they actually suggest) is to use the Realize Instances node to reduce the nesting.
But again, if you use a Geometry to Instance node after each Curve to Mesh node (in your case), you'll fix the problem and effectively only have about 5-6 levels. That's the amount I'd actually expect you to have without all that manipulations, but again, for some reason, that's not the case.

I didn't know that about the levels!  that's very good to know.  thanks for the answer

Quick solution (there might be better ones, as this does not tackle the root cause, but rather hammers the problem down)
Something in the context of the "instance on points" is traveling back in the node tree and affecting the positions of things. When you attach a viewer node, you don't propagate the full context of your tree, and the results are different.
So, if you "realize instances" before instancing again, you eliminate the context propagation. The only problem (which will only be noticed on very complext trees) is that "realize instances" increase the processing time.


this is the perfect solution!  this setup is only intended for low poly trees so realizing the instances works great
